# Bessel equation with another type of weight

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, bessel-functions

A research problem led me to consider the following modification of Bessel's equation:
$$
- \xi''(r) - \frac{N - 1}{r} \xi'(r) - \left(f(r) - \frac{\theta}{r^2} \right)\xi(r) = 0 \quad \text{in} \quad [0, 1]
$$
with boundary conditions
$$
\xi'(0) = 0, \ \xi(1) = 1.
$$

Of course some hypotheses on $f$ are required, but I can maybe adapt the problem to them.

> Is there any theory regarding such equations with the term $f(r)$ in place of the $1$ that appears in the classical Bessel equation? Any reference? In fact, it would suffice to have some information on $\xi'(1)$ or $\xi''(1)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $f(r)=r^p$ the solution is still a Bessel function, with argument $r^{1+p/2}$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thank you. Unfortunately this is too restrictive: $f(r) = g'(u(r))$, where $u$ is the radial solution of $- \Delta u = g(u)$ in the unit ball (with Dirichlet condition). Maybe some specific nonlinearity $g$ would give some good information?